# Is this (image provided) an Android component I can use? If so, what is it called?

Tags: android, android-widget, gallery, graphic

I have a gallery, and I want to include an onscreen graphic similar to that on the homescreen of my *Galaxy Tab*. Does anyone know what this is and how to use it, or do I need to make a custom component?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's called paging indicator - there is a nice library for that on github: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator